# React HTML-Canvas issue with setupCanvas() returning TypeError: Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas

First time using React in this way - trying to draw a basic mock-up canvas to start a new game but returning with 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setupCanvas' of undefined'.  Can anyone spot why?

> game.jsx

```
// initial game parameters and setup
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        rectHeight: React.PropTypes.number,
        rectWidth: React.PropTypes.number,
        width: React.PropTypes.number,
        height: React.PropTypes.number
    },
    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            rectHeight: 300,
            rectWidth: 25,
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        }
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {

        }
    },
    componentDidMount: () => {
        this.setupCanvas();
        this.draw()
    },
    canvas: undefined,
    context: undefined,
    canvasStyle: {
        margin: 'auto'
    },
    setupCanvas: () => {
        this.canvas = this.getDOMNode();
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    },
    draw() {
        this.context.fillRect(50, 50, this.rectWidth, this.rectHeight);
        this.context.save();
        this.context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <canvas 
              style={this.canvasStyle}
              width={this.props.width}
              height={this.props.height} />
        )
    }
});
```

> app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Game from './components/game';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Game />, document.getElementById('main')
);
```

> index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Intelligent Mouse</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='main'></div>
        <script src='bundle.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the arrow function expression, you are [lexically binding the this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to your function properties. However, because you are defining your functions as properties of your main class, you do not want to do this. Change property values to anonymous functions and it should work.

```
export default React.createClass({
propTypes: {
    rectHeight: React.PropTypes.number,
    rectWidth: React.PropTypes.number,
    width: React.PropTypes.number,
    height: React.PropTypes.number
},
getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
        rectHeight: 300,
        rectWidth: 25,
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    }
},
getInitialState: function() {
    return {

    }
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setupCanvas();
    this.draw()
},
canvas: undefined,
context: undefined,
canvasStyle: {
    margin: 'auto'
},
setupCanvas: function() {
    this.canvas = this.getDOMNode();
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
},
draw: function() {
    this.context.fillRect(50, 50, this.rectWidth, this.rectHeight);
    this.context.save();
    this.context.fillStyle = 'blue';
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <canvas 
          style={this.canvasStyle}
          width={this.props.width}
          height={this.props.height} />
    )
}
});
```

Comment: You're right thank you :)  Need to get deeper understanding of ES2015 binding.  Also fwiw .getDOMNode() is now deprecated and not working.  had to use ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this) even though not v0.15 yet.  https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html